# Get unitVector X Y Z values

Tags: vba, catia

i want to create lines on a surface using bunch of points, those lines must be in 5deg incremental
**(In Catia using VBA)**

here are the steps

Step:1 - first i will create lines using **normal to surface** option

Step:2 - then i measure the angle between **normaltosurface** line and **xyPlane** if the angle is near to **5deg mutiples** number for ex if angle is 81.23deg

Step:3 - then i should create a line using **point-direction option** which is **80deg** and if angle more than 82.5 and less than 87.5 then i should create a line using point-direction option which is 85deg to **XYPlane**

i need to get the X Y Z direction components (unit vectors in catia) which makes the angle between point-direction line and xyplane 5deg multiples like 80,85,90,95,100deg

[image]

the surface in the image is not actual surface

x y z components are unit vectors of line that i need to create
i know the angle, for that angle i need to find out the X Y Z unit vector values using VECTOR ROTATION IN 3D SPACE FORMULA

here is the image of that formula

[image]

here we know the value of **theta** using that we need to calculate **X Y Z** unit vector values

i need to this in VBA

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to sound rude but are you looking for help with your code or are you giving assignment in hoping someone will give you solution for free ?

Anyway to get the direction vectors you can use something like this

```
Dim TempVariant As Variant
Dim aOrigin(2) As Variant
Dim aDirection(2) As Variant
Dim NewLine As HybridShapeLineNormal

Set NewLine = ShapeFactory.AddNewLineNormal(RefSurface, PointReference, 0, 1, VectorOrient)

Set TempVariant = NewLine

Call TempVariant.GetOrigin(aOrigin) 'get starting point x y z
Call TempVariant.GetDirection(aDirection) 'get vectors x y z
```

EDIT

If you want to deal with 3D rotation you can take a look at this excel.
It took me a while myself (about week) and I found this excel somewhere years ago which helped me ... therefore I'm unable to give credits for this.

[Excel Euler angles](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aitnpui9s1cFiynQGb69d6hj4tmB?e=k3XFbd)

Comment: i understand DJakub i am not giving assignment to anyone, i have done 50% of vba coding the only part i needed is how do i implement vector rotation equation to get X Y Z values for specific angle(Theta value)

Comment: i see that's a tricky part :) maybe my edited answer can help you. I can't post my code for you.